# Play store silent auto-update of running app

Tags: android, auto-update, foreground

I'm working on an app that will be used on android tv sets as well as tablets mounted on walls. It simply cycles through some online content that is set up elsewhere. It will be running 24/7, cycling through and displaying content. All devices will have auto-updates enabled. My question is... will the device download and install the app update if the app is currently running in the foreground? I've already set up a broadcast receiver to restart the app after an update happens. I just don't know if it will update while the app is running.

Comment: From my experience, I have an App that has two services running in the background at all times. When the Play Store gets an update it updates my app like any other app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will automatically update, even if it is in the foreground.

But be warned, when the update occurs, Android will close the App if it is currently in the foreground and will not automatically relaunch it. If your App needs to run all the time, you'll need something to relaunch it following the update.

Comment: Great. This is what I wanted to know. As for your warning, will a broadcast receiver listening for ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED serve that purpose?

Comment: Oh and is there any rule of thumb as to when the apps will auto update? I've had an update out to the play store for almost 24 hrs now and still no update on the devices.

Comment: @adelphus Do you have any documentation for this? I've read other SO answers claiming that applications running in the foreground _do not_ auto update.

Answer (score 1):

from google docs (https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/9350374?hl=en)

> Default update behavior
>
> By default, apps are updated automatically when the following
> constraints are met:
>
> ```
> The device is connected to a Wi-Fi network.
> The device is charging.
> The device is idle (not actively used).
> The app to be updated is not running in the foreground.
> ```
>
> Google Play typically checks for app updates once a day, so it can
> take up to 24 hours before an app update is added to the update queue.
> After an app is added to the queue, it will be automatically updated
> the next time the constraints above are met.
>
> The next sections describe how end users and IT admins can change the
> default update behavior on their device.